# Issue with running a migration on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, migration, counter-cache

This is a follow up to this post  [Rails, data structure and performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7482975/rails-data-structure-and-performance), where I have attempted to create a Counter Cache on Rails. To not have it to default 0, I have also added updating the column to the existing count value in the database.

Running rake db:migrate on development works fine, even though it took a few hours to run.

But running the migration with heroku is giving me the following error :

```
==  AddVotesCount: migrating ==================================================
-- add_column(:options, :votes_count, :integer, {:default=>0})
   -> 0.0196s
/Users/ebellity/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:644:in `initialize': Operation timed out - connect(2) (Errno::ETIMEDOUT)
    from /Users/ebellity/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:644:in `open'
    from /Users/ebellity/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:644:in `block in connect'
    from /Users/ebellity/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:44:in `timeout'
    from /Users/ebellity/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:87:in `timeout'
    from /Users/ebellity/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:644:in `connect'
    from /Users/ebellity/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:637:in `do_start'
    from /Users/ebellity/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:626:in `start'
    from /Users/ebellity/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/request.rb:172:in `transmit'
    from /Users/ebellity/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/request.rb:64:in `execute'
    from /Users/ebellity/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/request.rb:33:in `execute'
    from /Users/ebellity/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/resource.rb:51:in `get'
    from /Users/ebellity/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/heroku-2.8.4/lib/heroku/client.rb:554:in `process'
    from /Users/ebellity/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/heroku-2.8.4/lib/heroku/client.rb:532:in `get'
    from /Users/ebellity/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/heroku-2.8.4/lib/heroku/client.rb:290:in `read'
    from /Users/ebellity/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/heroku-2.8.4/lib/heroku/client.rb:311:in `each'
    from /Users/ebellity/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/heroku-2.8.4/lib/heroku/command/run.rb:50:in `rake'
    from /Users/ebellity/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/heroku-2.8.4/lib/heroku/command.rb:114:in `run'
    from /Users/ebellity/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/heroku-2.8.4/bin/heroku:14:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/ebellity/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/bin/heroku:19:in `load'
    from /Users/ebellity/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/bin/heroku:19:in `<main>'
```

I have tried a few different things but seem lost at this point, any help appreciated ! The strange thing is that the error message does not always come up instantly, sometimes it takes 10/20 minutes as if the migration was running.

Thanks

Update : here is the content of my migration file :

```
class AddVotesCount < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :options, :votes_count, :integer, :default => 0
    Option.all.each do |option|
       option.votes_count = option.votes.count
       option.save!
     end
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :options, :votes_count
  end
end
```

Update 2 : This works in staging environment with heroku... but not in production

After a few modifications, the migration code is now :

```
def self.up
    add_column :options, :votes_count, :integer, :default => 0
    Option.reset_column_information
    Option.find_each do |option|
      Option.reset_counters option.id, :votes
    end
```

and the error is :

```
==  AddVotesCount: migrating ==================================================
-- add_column(:options, :votes_count, :integer, {:default=>0})
-> 0.0224s
/Users/ebellity/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:644:in `initialize': getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known (SocketError)
        from /Users/ebellity/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:644:in `open'
        from /Users/ebellity/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:644:in `block in connect'
        from /Users/ebellity/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:44:in `timeout'
        from /Users/ebellity/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:87:in `timeout'
        from /Users/ebellity/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:644:in `connect'
        from /Users/ebellity/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:637:in `do_start'
        from /Users/ebellity/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:626:in `start'
        from /Users/ebellity/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/request.rb:172:in `transmit'
        from /Users/ebellity/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/request.rb:64:in `execute'
        from /Users/ebellity/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/request.rb:33:in `execute'
        from /Users/ebellity/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/resource.rb:51:in `get'
        from /Users/ebellity/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/heroku-2.8.4/lib/heroku/client.rb:554:in `process'
        from /Users/ebellity/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/heroku-2.8.4/lib/heroku/client.rb:532:in `get'
        from /Users/ebellity/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/heroku-2.8.4/lib/heroku/client.rb:290:in `read'
        from /Users/ebellity/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/heroku-2.8.4/lib/heroku/client.rb:311:in `each'
        from /Users/ebellity/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/heroku-2.8.4/lib/heroku/command/run.rb:50:in `rake'
        from /Users/ebellity/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/heroku-2.8.4/lib/heroku/command.rb:114:in `run'
        from /Users/ebellity/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/heroku-2.8.4/bin/heroku:14:in `<top (required)>'
        from /Users/ebellity/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/bin/heroku:19:in `load'
        from /Users/ebellity/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/bin/heroku:19:in `<main>'
```

Comment: What are the contents of your migration file?

Comment: @Dogbert just edited the question to add the migration file

Comment: Completey asside, but do you really need this migration. Could you not just create a method in the Option model called votes_count, which returned votes.count?

Comment: @Yule it seems like the "correct" way to do this is through CounterCache, it would increment the count automatically each time there is a new vote...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those who might face the same error, I got in touch with heroku and they told me to run the migration with this:

```
$ heroku run bash --app appname
```

then

```
$ rake db:migrate
```

For some reason, it worked...

Comment: +1 for `$ heroku run bash`. I didn't know you can run bash attached to your local terminal.